# Javascript Calculator only returns undefined

Tags: javascript, html, undefined

Please help. I am working on a simple Javascript Calculator. It will only return undefined. Ive looked over the code multiple times. I dont believe it is a typo error, but i cant seem to figue it out any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
function calc(a,b,op) {
    var a = parseInt(document.querySelector("#value1").value);
    var b = parseInt(document.querySelector("#value2").value);
    var op = document.querySelector("#operator").value;
    var calculate;

    if (op == "add"){
        calculate == a + b;
    }else if (op =="min"){
        calculate == a - b;
    }else if (op =="mult"){
        calculate == a * b;
    }else if (op =="div"){
        calculate == a / b;
    }
    document.querySelector("#results").innerHTML = calculate;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <form>
            Value 1: <input type="text" id="value1">
            
            Operator: <select name="" id="operator">
                <option value="add">Add</option>
                <option value="min">Subtract</option>
                <option value="mult">Multiply</option>
                <option value="div">Divide</option>
            </select>
            Value 2: <input type="text" id="value2">
            <button type="button" onclick="calc()">Calculate</button>
        </form>
        <div id="results"></div>

    
    </body>
<script src="hello.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: parseInt wont work with fractions

Answer (score 1):

`==` is for comparison. You need assignment in your `if` branches, which is `=`.

Also, nothing is allowed between `</body>` and `</html>`. Your `script` element should be just prior to the closing `body` tag.

Finally, don't use `.innerHTML` if you can avoid it (which you almost always can) as it has security and performance implications. Since you aren't working with an HTML string anyway, use `.textContent`.

```js
function calc(a,b,op) {
    var a = parseInt(document.querySelector("#value1").value);
    var b = parseInt(document.querySelector("#value2").value);
    var op = document.querySelector("#operator").value;
    var calculate;

    if (op == "add"){       // <-- Compare here with ==
        calculate = a + b;  // Assign here with =
    }else if (op =="min"){
        calculate = a - b;
    }else if (op =="mult"){
        calculate = a * b;
    }else if (op =="div"){
        calculate = a / b;
    }
    document.querySelector("#results").textContent = calculate;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <form>
            Value 1: <input type="text" id="value1">
            
            Operator: <select name="" id="operator">
                <option value="add">Add</option>
                <option value="min">Subtract</option>
                <option value="mult">Multiply</option>
                <option value="div">Divide</option>
            </select>
            Value 2: <input type="text" id="value2">
            <button type="button" onclick="calc()">Calculate</button>
        </form>
        <div id="results"></div>

      <!-- Script should be here -->
      <script src="hello.js"></script>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `==` should be `===`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone `==` is equality with implicit conversion and `===` is strict equality. While I agree that `===` is the best way to generally go, `==` is perfectly fine when you are ok with implicit conversion (and in some cases that's more desirable and strict equality check).

Comment: no linter sees `==` as perfectly fine, also a, b and op are already defined

Comment: @LawrenceCherone A linter will not flag `==` as an error. At most it will be a warning and one that you can configure your linter not to flag if you wish. Linters are great, but they can't understand the context of your code or your intent. That's where knowledge and experience come in. Implicit conversion can be a very powerful and desirable feature for an application. And, the fact that the variables are already defined has no bearing on how `==` would work.

Answer (score 1):

calculate == a + b;

You only need a single =;

It should be

```
    if (op == "add"){
        calculate = a + b;
    }else if (op =="min"){
        calculate = a - b;
    }else if (op =="mult"){
        calculate = a * b;
    }else if (op =="div"){
        calculate = a / b;
    }
```

Comment: How is this any different/better than the answer that was already posted before you answered?

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple typo

`=` is assignment

`==` is equality check

change `calculate ==`  to `calculate =`

Comment: How is this any different/better than the answer that was already posted before you answered?

Answer (score 1):

You were assigning two times, `calculate == a + b;` instead of `calculate = a + b;`

```js
function calc(a,b,op) {
    var a = parseInt(document.querySelector("#value1").value);
    var b = parseInt(document.querySelector("#value2").value);
    var op = document.querySelector("#operator").value;
    var calculate;

    if (op === "add") {
        calculate = a + b;
    } else if (op === "min") {
        calculate = a - b;
    } else if (op === "mult") {
        calculate = a * b;
    } else if (op === "div") {
        calculate = a / b;
    }
    document.querySelector("#results").innerHTML = calculate;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <form>
            Value 1: <input type="text" id="value1">
            
            Operator: <select name="" id="operator">
                <option value="add">Add</option>
                <option value="min">Subtract</option>
                <option value="mult">Multiply</option>
                <option value="div">Divide</option>
            </select>
            Value 2: <input type="text" id="value2">
            <button type="button" onclick="calc()">Calculate</button>
        </form>
        <div id="results"></div>

    
    </body>
<script src="hello.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: How is this any different/better than the answer that was already posted before you answered?

Answer (score -1):

```
function calc() {
    var a = parseInt(document.querySelector("#value1").value);
    var b = parseInt(document.querySelector("#value2").value);
    var op = document.querySelector("#operator").value;
    var calculate=0;
console.log(a+" "+b+" "+op)
    if (op == "add"){
        calculate = a + b;
        console.log(calculate)
    }else if (op =="min"){
        calculate = a - b;
    }else if (op =="mult"){
        calculate = a * b;
    }else if (op =="div"){
        calculate = a / b;
    }
    document.querySelector("#results").innerHTML = calculate;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <form>
            Value 1: <input type="text" id="value1">
            
            Operator: <select name="" id="operator">
                <option value="add">Add</option>
                <option value="min">Subtract</option>
                <option value="mult">Multiply</option>
                <option value="div">Divide</option>
            </select>
            Value 2: <input type="text" id="value2">
            <button type="button" onclick="calc()">Calculate</button>
        </form>
        <div id="results"></div>

    
    </body>
<script src="hello.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: How is this any different/better than the answer that was already posted before you answered?

Comment: In some previous answers calc() is accepting parameter , parameters are not send on onclick event .That is little bit update from others